# Create Event with NSDate

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios-4.2

is there any way to create events for NSDate ? here is my code

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];       
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 
    myDate.text = dateStr;
```

for example if date = 12 FEB ;
 myDate .text = @"Mother Day";

something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure it is. You have to split the date into day and month using NSDateComponents

You could write a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate *)date isSameAsDay:(NSInteger)day andMonth:(NSInteger)month {
    NSUInteger dateFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:dateFlags fromDate:date];
    if ([components day] == day && [components month] == month) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and you would use it like this

```
if ([self date:[NSDate date] isSameAsDay:12 andMonth:2]) {
   myDate.text = @"Mother Day";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // Get ref to todays date
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
    [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
    NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday]; // Sun == 1, Mon == 2, Tue...
    NSInteger weekdayOrdinal = [weekdayComponents weekdayOrdinal]; // First weekday month == 1 etc...
    NSInteger month = [weekdayComponents month];
    NSLog (@"%i %i %i", weekday, weekdayOrdinal, month);

    // Mothers day is every second Sunday of May so weekday == 1, weekdayOrdinal == 2, month == 5
    if ((weekday == 1) && (weekdayOrdinal == 2) && (month == 5)) {
        NSLog (@"It's mothers day!");
    }
    [gregorian release];
```